# How to pass an object with template function?

Tags: c++

Doing my homework, got stuck on the template function part. I have the following `main()` in my `.cpp` file:

```
int main() 
{
Pair<char> letters('a', 'd');
cout << "\nThe first letter is: " << letters.getFirst();
cout << "\nThe second letter is: " << letters.getSecond();

cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I need to use `template` to make the `class` exchageable, and here is what I have in the `.h` file:

```
template <class T>
class Pair
{
private:    
  T letters;
public:
  T getFirst();
  T getSecond();
};
```

now, in my VS, it says both `getFrist()` and `getSecond()` are not found. How am I supposed to pass T as a `class` in `template`?

Comment: by the way, your code isn't complete. You're missing the declaration of your two-argument constructor.

Answer (score 4):

you don't have an implementation on `Pair<T>::getFirst` / `getSecond` in your `.h` file, do you? That's a common pitfall; your compiler needs to "see" what `Pair<char>::getFirst()` actually is at *compile* time.

When you've got the object together, and *link* the individual compilation units together, it's already too late.

Hence, put the implementation of your template methods in your header.

Also, don't re-invent the wheel. A `char letters[2]` is just as useful as your pair, and if you actually need key/value pairs, `std::pair` is what you want – it's even the core of associative containers like `std::map`.